# Infinite series convergence with the root test

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$  be my series, I want to find out if my series converges or not

$a_n = (\frac {1}{3} - \frac {1}{2n})^n$ for n = 2k

$a_n = (1 - \frac {1}{2n})^{n^2}$ for n = 2k+1

by the root test I got that the first one equals to $1/3 < 1$
and the second one to $1/\sqrt e <1$

so I  have proven that the 2 individual series lets say converge. How do I prove that the series as a whole converge?

Comment: Did you try with the root test?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter thats what i used and prove that both $\sum an$ for n=2k and for n=2k+1 converge but i want to prove it as a whole

Comment: So you need to prove this:  if $S_1 := \sum_k a_{2k}$ and $S_2:=\sum_k a_{2k+1}$ both converge, then $S:=\sum_n a_n$ converges.  To do it, use the definition for convergence of a series.  Start by showing that each partial sum for $S$ is obtained by adding a partial sum for $S_1$ and a partial sum of $S_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to argue that $\sum a_n$ converges. You've shown by the root test that the series $\sum b_n$ converges, where
$$b_n:=\left(\frac13 -\frac1{2n}\right)^n$$
and that the series $\sum c_n$ converges, where
$$c_n:=\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n^2}.$$
Notice that $\sum a_n$ is taking its odd terms from $(c_n)$, and its even terms from $(b_n)$. Since each $c_n$ is non-negative, and each $b_n$ is non-negative when $n\ge 2$, you have the inequality
$$0\le a_n\le b_n + c_n\tag1$$
when $n\ge 2$. (The idea: $a_n$ is either $b_n$ or $c_n$, which are both non-negative, hence $a_n$ is at most the sum of $b_n$ and $c_n$.) Inequality (1) implies that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$ converges, by the comparison test. So tossing in the $n=1$ term, you conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.  (The argument would be less fussy if it were true that $b_n\ge0$ for all $n$.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use [root test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) since  it is easy to find $\lim\sup \vert a_n \vert ^{1/n}$.

Edit :

I assume that you are familiar with the concept of [limit superior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior).

> If $n$ is even then $|a_n|^{1/n} \to 1/3$ and if $n$ is odd then $|a_n|^{1/n} \to 1/\sqrt e$. So $\lim\sup \vert a_n \vert ^{1/n} = 1/\sqrt e < 1$. So by root test the corresponding series converges.

Answer (score 0):

- $0<\frac 13-\frac 1{2n}<\frac 13$
- $0<(1-\frac 1{2n})^n\to \frac 1{\sqrt{e}}<\frac 23\quad$ and by chosing a small $\epsilon$, the expression is also $<\frac 23$ for $n\gg 1$.

So for $n$ large enough $|a_n|<\left(\frac 23\right)^n$ and the series converge absolutely by comparision test.